# React Native - Register Screen not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I can't submit a form. My states:

```
function RegisterScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({
    name: "",
    surname: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    password2: "",
  });
```

onSubmit:

```
const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    const { name, email, password, password2 } = formData;
    console.log(formData);
  };
```

Return here: Inputs. I did onChangeText and value here.

```
return (
  <View>
      <TextInput
        placeholder={i18n.t("name")}
        value={formData.name}
        onChangeText={(name) => setFormData(name)}
        id="name"
        required
      />
    <TextInput
      placeholder={i18n.t("email")}
      value={formData.email}
      onChangeText={(email) => setFormData(email)}
      id="email"
      required
    />
    <TextInput
      secureTextEntry={true}
      placeholder={i18n.t("password")}
      value={formData.password}
      onChangeText={(password) => setFormData(password)}
      id="password"
    />

    <Button
      title={i18n.t("register")}
      onPress={() => onSubmit()}
    />
  </View>
);   }
```

It just returns password. I am expecting all form data. I think the code has an error.

Comment: Any Error on submit ?

Comment: @parainamk let me know if my answer works for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's because this is overwriting everything at the end:

`onChangeText={(password) => setFormData(password)}`

you need to do

```
onChangeText={(name) => setFormData({...formData, name})}
onChangeText={(email) => setFormData({...formData, email})}
onChangeText={(password) => setFormData({...formData, password})}
```